# как изменить цвет надписи "нажмите еще раз для выхода из приложения"

Tags: android-studio

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]как изменить цвет надписи "нажмите еще раз для выхода из приложения"?

Comment: Думаю стоит показать как вы получаете эту надпись.

Comment: Поставьте вопрос корректно. Вам дают ответы гадая на кофейной гуще. Предоставьте код.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
TextView tw;
tw.setTextColor(Color.RED);
```

цвет гарантированно изменится